# Refreshing JSON input in Select Box after Resolve / Promise in Sweet Alert 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, promise, sweetalert2

I have a sweet alert 2 select input box that is populated by an external JSON file

```
var inputOptionsPromise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/so/categories.json", function(data) {
            resolve(data)
        });
    }, 500)
})
```

This JSON file contains a list of categories one can choose, or a last option of key value pair of `"Add Category +"`

```
title: 'Select Category',
input: 'select',
inputClass: 'swal-select-category',
inputPlaceholder: 'Please Select',
inputOptions: inputOptionsPromise,
inputValidator: (value) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        if (value === '') {
            resolve('You need to input a category!');
        } else if (value === 'Add Category +') {
            alertify.prompt('Category Name', '', function(evt, value) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    async: false,
                    url: 'http://localhost/sa/resources/scripts/addcategory.php',
                    data: {
                        data: value
                    },
                    success: function() {
                        alertify.success('Category ' + value + ' Added.');
                        resolve(value + ' Category Added');
                    },
                    failure: function() {
                        alert("Error Adding Category!");
                        resolve('Error!');
                    }
                });
            }, function() {
                resolve('You need to input a category!');
            });
        } else {
            resolve()
        }
    })
}
```

As you can see if the user chooses the select option `Add Category +`, a pop-up input box that performs an AJAX request to a PHP page to append whatever input (new Category) to this JSON file.

This works as intended, and a user can either choose a pre-existing category in the JSON file or add a Category to the JSON file using the mentioned option.

After all this work, though, an unfortunate pitfall in this case, is that the input box/JSON is not refreshed once a new Category is appended to the JSON file.

If a user refreshes the page, or exits the sweet alert 2 queue again, it reloads the JSON and displays the new category inputted -- but not whilst in the sweet alert 2 existing dialogue box that the user is expecting to choose his or her category in.

Is it possible to refresh my `inputOptionsPromise` var to get the new JSON values within the inputValidator or Resolve?

I've added a custom class to the sweet alert 2... must I use some hack-ish jquery solution to possibly refresh the select options or is there a better way to go about getting refreshed JSON data while entering and exiting a promise/resolve?

Comment: Wouldn't normally expect a validator to do anything more than validate.

Comment: *sighs* I see that now.  In a way it is validating a proper category input-- with the added feature of being able to add a custom category-- at least that was my thought process.  Now I am trying to work backwards, I suppose :P

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up adding this bit of jQuery to insert the option value as the second select option. Works fine and doesn't require a json refresh. Probably better.

```
$('.swal2-select option:first').after($('<option />', { 'value': value, text: value }));
$('.swal2-select option[value="' + value + '"]').attr('selected','selected');
```

or

```
$.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: 'http://localhost/sa/resources/scripts/addcategory.php',
        data: { data: value },
        success: function () {                
          alertify.success('Category ' + value + ' Added.');
        $('.swal2-select option:first').after($('<option />', { 'value': value, text: value }));
        $('.swal2-select option[value="' + value + '"]').attr('selected','selected');
          resolve(value + ' Category Added');
        },
        failure: function() {
          alert("Error Adding Category!");
          resolve('Error!');
        }
    });
```